# Why bigint number not split with c# CultureInfo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, string-formatting, cultureinfo

I'm beginner in C#, i have a currency field in SQL server, and that field's data type is `bigint`

For example I have this number:

```
12598546
```

I want to show it in this format:

```
12,598,546
```

My C# code for it:

```
query_statusOfRPTOST[i].price_year.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-US"))
```

That code in my local PC works fine, but when application runs in server, number is shown in following format:

```
12598,546
```

What's happening? And how can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into `NumberFormat` of this `CultureInfo` you will see next:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-US");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes));
//output: 3,0
```

What means, according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes(v=vs.110).aspx) that to the left of decimal separator first group will contain 3 digits, and other will not be groupped.

If you want to get required value presented in format with groupping, you should do the one of following:

1. Create specific culture, based on `es-US` and set `NumberGroupSizes` as `[3]`.
2. Use another existing `CultureInfo` with predefined `NumberGroupSizes` with `[3]` - for example, `en-US`.
3. Use special formatting, as Ali suggested

Code example for first:

```
long a = 12598546;
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-US");
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3 };
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("N0", culture));
// output 12,598,546
```

Code example for second:

```
long a = 12598546;
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
// output 12,598,546
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.Format like this:

```
string.Format("{0:#,###0}", query_statusOfRPTOST[i].price_year)
```